# Why doesn't g++'s option "-Winline" work?

Tags: c++, assembly

When I compiled a cpp program using `g++ -Winline xx.cpp`, I got no warning about the incorrect inline declaration.
My code is

```
#include <iostream>
inline int test(int n)
{
    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        res+=i;
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    int n=100;
    int mul=test(n);
    std::cout<<mul<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly code of main is:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x080485f4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080485f5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080485f7 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080485fa <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x080485fd <+9>: movl   $0x64,0x18(%esp)
   0x08048605 <+17>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x08048609 <+21>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804860c <+24>:    call   0x804869c <test(int)>
   0x08048611 <+29>:    mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048615 <+33>:    mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048619 <+37>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804861d <+41>:    movl   $0x804a040,(%esp)
   0x08048624 <+48>:    call   0x80484c0 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
   0x08048629 <+53>:    movl   $0x8048530,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048631 <+61>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048634 <+64>:    call   0x8048520 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
   0x08048639 <+69>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0804863e <+74>:    leave  
   0x0804863f <+75>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

It is clear that test is not inlined, but I wonder why there's no warning about it.

Comment: Which version of GCC?

Comment: Oh and by the way, you have undefined behavior in your `test` function, as you forgot to initialize the `res` variable.

Comment: Doesn't default `g++` invocation imply `-O0` ? - In this case: "GCC will not inline any functions if the -fno-inline option is used or if -O0 is used. Otherwise, GCC may still be unable to inline a function for many reasons; the -Winline option may be used ..."

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The version is 4.6.3. Sorry for my mistake, and I just corrected it.

Comment: @abyss.7 Yes, you are right. But even if I add `-O` option, and I declare an incorrect inline function such as an inline virtual function, I still get no warning information.

Comment: How the assembly code helps here ?

Answer (score 2):

As also stated in the comments (by abyss.7), you won't get inlining unless you enable optimizations (even -O1 would be enough). However your current code would get further optimized then (gcc can statically compute the result), so you won't see that.

Instead, consider a slightly different code:

```
#include <iostream>

int delta = 1;

inline int test(int n)
{
    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        res *= delta;
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    int n=100;
    int mul=test(n);
    std::cout<<mul<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The fact that delta is declared globally prevents the compiler from statically optimizing it at this level (since it might be changed by another function). Changing the `+=` to `*=` prevents it from being multiplied by n and added once, so you would still get the loop.

Compiling with gcc 4.2.2 (oldest one i could find) with no optimizations, you get -

```
0000000000400a64 <main>:
  400a64:       55                      push   %rbp
  400a65:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400a68:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400a6c:       c7 45 f8 64 00 00 00    movl   $0x64,0xfffffffffffffff8(%rbp)
  400a73:       8b 7d f8                mov    0xfffffffffffffff8(%rbp),%edi
  400a76:       e8 25 00 00 00          callq  400aa0 <_Z4testi>
  400a7b:       89 45 fc                mov    %eax,0xfffffffffffffffc(%rbp)
  400a7e:       8b 75 fc                mov    0xfffffffffffffffc(%rbp),%esi
  400a81:       bf b0 12 50 00          mov    $0x5012b0,%edi
  400a86:       e8 1d fd ff ff          callq  4007a8 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
  400a8b:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400a8e:       be d8 07 40 00          mov    $0x4007d8,%esi
  400a93:       e8 20 fd ff ff          callq  4007b8 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
  400a98:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400a9d:       c9                      leaveq
  400a9e:       c3                      retq
```

Compiling with -O1, it turns into

```
000000000040083c <main>:
  40083c:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400840:       8b 15 12 05 10 00       mov    1049874(%rip),%edx        # 500d58 <delta>
  400846:       be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  40084b:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400850:       0f af f2                imul   %edx,%esi
  400853:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400856:       83 f8 64                cmp    $0x64,%eax
  400859:       75 f5                   jne    400850 <main+0x14>
  40085b:       bf 60 0d 50 00          mov    $0x500d60,%edi
  400860:       e8 73 fe ff ff          callq  4006d8 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
  400865:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400868:       e8 7b fe ff ff          callq  4006e8 <_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@plt>
  40086d:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400872:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400876:       c3                      retq
```

So the loop got obviously inlined

**EDIT**

The reason why -Winline doesn't report a warning is that without optimizations gcc never even **tries** to perform the inline (and therefor doesn't fail).

Adding a variable length array in my above function :

```
char buf[n];
```

and compiling **with** -O1, produces the following warning:

```
test2.cpp:5: warning: function 'int test(int)' can never be inlined because it uses alloca (override using the always_inline attribute
```

Comment: But, even if I use virtual incorrectly (inline virtual function in a Base class) and add `-O -Winline` option, I get no warning information. That's wired. My gcc version is 4.6.3.

Comment: Interesting that the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out that `test()` will always return 0. :)

Comment: @unwind - right. If I move `int delta` declaration inside it does eliminate the entire loop, because it can calculate it out front, but it should have been able to eliminate that regardless of deltas' value. Cool :)